# Как описать сущности для чата JPA

Tags: java, mysql, база-данных, hibernate, jpa

Есть задача реализовать чат на бэке.

Спроектировал вот такую базу[image: база]
Не знаю, как правильно описать сущности.

По коду следующее:
`User` имеет лишь `Set` с `Chat`, который не знаю как описать для хибера.

`Chat` выглядит вот так

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "chats")
public class Chat {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
private Long id;

//TODO замапить чаты у юзера и тут

private UserModel UserOne;

private UserModel UserTwo;

@OneToMany(
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        mappedBy = "chat"
)
private Set<ChatMessage> chatMessageSet;
}
```

`ChatMessage`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "chat_messages")
public class ChatMessage {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne(
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY
)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private UserModel user;

@ManyToOne(
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY
)
@JoinColumn(name = "chat_id")
private Chat chat;

@Column(name = "text_msg", nullable = false)
private String textMsg;

@Column(name = "created_time", nullable = false)
private LocalDate createdTime;
}
```

Comment: Set лучше не использовать

Comment: https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-multiplebagfetchexception/ - Вот статья. Чем больше у вас будет данных ( А у Вас как раз чат), то тем больше будет тратиться компьютерных ресурсов на решение проблемы

Comment: @Antonio112009, спасибо за ответ, я что-то уже набросал и хотел удалить вопрос.
Долго не мог понять, но наконец дошло в чём проблема)
Даже если использовать больше запросов(что также будет требовать больше ресурсов), всё равно мне кажется Set тут можно использовать. Порядок вставки мне не важен, да и сортировать Set быстрее. 
У меня мало опыта, объясните, если я не прав

Comment: Трудно с ходу объяснить. Данная рекомендация идёт не от меня а от одного из разработчиков данной технологии. Vlad Mihalcea в той статье (он и есть один из тех разработчиков) обьясняет, что при работе с 10 - 20 данными Set может справиться спокойно со своей задачей, однако при работе с крупными данными, set начинает потреблять больше мощностей компьютера

Comment: Хотя может я и не прав. В ManyToMany имеет смысл использовать Set. У Thorben-... (Раньше - thoughts-on-Java) была таблица, про выбор между set и list. Во всех случаях он использовал list, кроме ManyToMany, где он вставлял set

Comment: Кстати, вот статья - https://thorben-janssen.com/association-mappings-bag-list-set/